# Implicit Interpolating function in Mathematica and its explicit form in small sections

Tags: interpolation

I have a set of points $\{x_i,y_i\}$ that represents a closed curve. I want to find a function $F(x,y)$ such that $F(x,y) = 0$ gives the needed curve and $F(x,y) \ne 0$ outside the curve.

For example, suppose I am given a set of points that forms a circle:

```
n = 16;
points = Drop[Table[{Cos[2 i Pi], Sin[2 i Pi]}, {i, 0, 1, 1/n}], -1] // N;
```

I use the `Interpolation[..]` Mathematica function:

```
args = Join[Table[{points[[i]], 0}, {i, Length[points]}], {{{0, 0}, -1}}];
F = Interpolation[args];
```

Here I have added a new point $(0,0)$ with value $-1$ in it to my set of points to give "a depth" to $F(x,y)$.

First question. Is that solution right? Can I be sure that my $F(x,y) \ne 0$ on non-curve points if I add "an inner" point with non-zero value to my set? What solution is more preferable?

Also I have a second (and main) question. Due the peculiarity of my problem I need an explicit expression for my curve in a given section. In other words I want to have an expression for my curve in terms $y = f(x)$ or $x = f(y)$ (does not matter) between near points. I need this $f$ and its derivative $f'$. Thereby $f$ should be an InterpolatingFunction object too (but one-dimensional).

Using `Solve` on `F` from previous example does not give a result.

How to get $F$ and $f$ (between given near points)?

**Update**:

In my example $F(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1$ and I can single out two explicit fucntions: $f_1(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ where $x > 0$ and $f_2(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ where $x \leq 0$. Equations $y=f_1(x), y=f_2(x)$ and equation $F(x,y)=0$ represent the same curve (a circle). This is what I need: implicit function $F(x,y)$ and a set of explicit functions $f_i$.

Also I can single out another explicit functions:

$f_1(y) = \sqrt{1-y^2}$ where $y \leq x$ and $y \geq -x$;
 $f_2(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ where $y > x$ and $y \geq -x$;
 $f_3(y) = -\sqrt{1-y^2}$ where $y > x$ and $ y < -x$;
 $f_4(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ where $y \leq x$ and $y < -x$.

Together they form a circle.

**Update 2**:

The given curve is closed and has no self-intersections. Locally $F(x,y)=0$ can be expressed as $y=f(x)$ or $x=f(y)$. This is what I need. I try Solve function but it does not give result for interpolating $F(x,y)$. Instead it gives an error: *"Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system"*

Comment: Might make sense instead to interpolate each coordinate separately as a function of a new parameter, call it t. So you would have x[t] and y[t] as parametrized functions. If you require x[y] or y[x] you could either (a) locally invert (say) x[t] to get t[x] and thus find y[t[x]], or (b) break the points into sections monotonic in one or the other variable, and use that to form interpolations of one in terms of the other.

Comment: It does not give me the implicit function $F(x,y)$ (determinated within whole plane). Maybe I can construct it in some way based on $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ then I solve the problem. But now I wonder is there an evident/build-in method to obtain this $F(x,y)$ at once.

Comment: @ddd You can interpolate each coordinate separately and use implicization techniques to obtain F(x,y), such as computing the resultant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Implicitization_of_a_rational_curve

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your second question, `f` may be obtained in general via `f=Interpolation[points]`. Its derivative is given by `f'[.3]` (say) This, however, fails for your example because two points with the same x-coordinate appear (as it is a circle).

For instance, try `f = Interpolation[Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 10, .1}]]` and then `Plot[f'[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`.

Perhaps you could explain what it is you're actually trying to do.

EDIT: OK, you can do this for `f1`:

```
Quiet[f1 = FunctionInterpolation[Sqrt[1 - y^2], {y, -1, 1}]];
```

and for your `F` (that I randomly renamed to `func`)

```
func = FunctionInterpolation[-1 + 1*(x^2 + y^2), {x, -1.5, 
   1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

Note that this is some function that vanishes on the unit circle. If all you want is that `F(x,y)` vanishes on (eg) the unit circle, there are infinitely many functions satisfying this; one of them is the one you gave.

Comment: Thak you for your remark. I added some explanation according to my example.

Comment: The problem is i do not know these Sqrt and x^2+y^2. I have a set of points that form a pretty complicated curve (without intersections). I need implicit function (any) that vanishes on this curve (determinated for all x,y and non-zero in non-curve points) and a set of explicit functions (they determinated only in some sections) such that their graphics coincide with curve

Comment: You seem to be asking too much, darksowa.  For instance, if your points follow a lemniscate $F(x,y)$ = $(x^2 + y^2)^2 - (x^2 - y^2)=0$ then in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ there does not exist any such $f$.

Comment: My curve has no self-intersections. Locally $F(x,y)=0$ can be expressed as $y=f(x)$ or $x=f(y)$. This is what I need. I tryed Solve function but it does not give result for interpolating $F(x,y)$. Instead it gives an error "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system"

Comment: You will run into problems with cusps, too.  Although the *intended* function may have none of these problems, the ones based on *interpolating* the points very well could have them.  Furthermore, although it's fair to hope that you could assemble an atlas of local maps of the form $f_i(x)$ and $f_j(y)$, if they are created via interpolation from your discrete data, it is unlikely these functions will exactly agree on their areas of overlap!

Comment: As I understand from your message there is some trouble with obtaining a "good" $F(x,y)$. I supposed this problem was well-known and solved. Google shows me there is some method named "Smoothing thin plate spline". I'm going to dig out in this direction

Answer (score 1):

In addition to that inner point, provide a bounding box (or other curve) with a constant value larger than 0. That way you will have an interpolating function that does what you want over a reasonable range.

You'll probably want to give more points on your curve. Here I double it to 32.

```
n = 32;
points = Drop[Table[{Cos[2. i Pi], Sin[2. i Pi]}, {i, 0, 1, 1/n}], -1];
innerpoint = {{0, 0}, -1};
bigsize = 10;
bigval = 5;
outerbox = Union[Join[
    Table[{{bigsize, j}, bigval}, {j, -bigsize, bigsize}],
    Table[{{-bigsize, j}, bigval}, {j, -bigsize, bigsize}],
    Table[{{j, bigsize}, bigval}, {j, -bigsize, bigsize}],
    Table[{{j, -bigsize}, bigval}, {j, -bigsize, bigsize}]]];
args = Join[Thread[{points, 0}], {innerpoint}, outerbox];

twodimFunction = Interpolation[args];

Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently
only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All.
Order will be reduced to 1. >>`

ContourPlot[
 twodimFunction[x, y], {x, -bigsize, bigsize}, {y, -bigsize, bigsize},
  ContourLabels -> True, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

It's a bit fuzzy at some of the outer contours. No idea why; must just be a vagary of the plotting sampling. Setting the PlotPoints reasonably high helps to alleviate it visually, and shows that it is not the interpolation that is to blame.